# Resolving duplicate polkadot dependencies polkadot typescript sdk

Tags: polkadot-js

I am currently using the polkadot sdk in my typescript project and while I was attempting to upgrade their versions, I deleted my yarn.lock file and reran yarn install but now I get this when I try and run the project

[image: screenshot]

I saw online that yarn dedupe would help but since I am already using yarn v2, it should be built in and thus I am not able to run that command manually.

Here are the three polkadot dependencies I am trying to import into my project: [image]

I'm struggling to figure out how to fix this as I don't want to have to rely on manually going in and deleting duplicate packets every time I do a fresh yarn install.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your libraries? If so, I suggest you look into a project that works and use the same configuration and example [PolkadotJS](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/package.json) or [Polkadot Staking Dashboard](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-staking-dashboard/blob/main/package.json).

```json
"@polkadot/api": "^10.9.1",
"@polkadot/keyring": "^12.3.2",
"@polkadot/util-crypto": "^12.3.2",
```